# What is the best file system/allocation size combination for the following :

Tags: usb, usb-storage

Kingston Data Traveler 2GB

Moserbaer 4GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tests confirm FAT32 best filesystem for USB Drives](http://www.kongtechnology.com/2009/02/12/tests-confirm-fat32-best-filesystem-for-usb-drives/)